# React Firebase authentication redirects randomly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, local-storage

I got help from another user here on StackOverflow a couple of weeks ago, with creating authentication for my website. Here is the current code:

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
    const userKey = Object.keys(window.localStorage)
  .filter(it => it.startsWith('firebase:authUser'))[0];
const user = userKey ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(userKey)) : undefined; 
   if (user) {
      return <Route {...props} />
   } else {
    return <Redirect to='/admin'/>
   }
}


export default PrivateRoute;
```

However, when I navigate to the specific routes that I have defined as a PrivateRoute, it just so happens that it randomly redirects to the login page, even though I am logged in. How could I prevent this form happening? Should I delay it with 0.5 seconds using setTimeout(), or is that considered a rather 'bad way of solving the problem'?

Comment: It's not recommended to hack localStorage to detect active user. There is no guarantee it would work. For example, Firebase could change implementation to use indexDB to store user state. To detect a signed in user, you could use onAuthStateChanged listener. There are lots of docs or guide out there.

Comment: @TiWang So would that require me to use Redux?